# Regex to replace dot notation by brackets in query string

Tags: regex

Basically I'm trying to replace this: `a.b.c=17.5.2017&x.y=z`

with this:
`a[b][c]=17.5.2017&x[y]=z`

I have found a regular expression online a while ago, it looks like this:

```
[.]([^.]*?)(?=[=.&]|$)
```

Now, this works, but it also replaces values in the query string. Meaning in my original example, the date (17.5.2017) gets replaced by 17[5][2017], see here:

https://regex101.com/r/5IzNov/1/

What I am thinking of would be to only match if there was not the **=** symbol before the **&** symbol or it's the beginning of the string. However I have no idea how to do this. I assume I will need a conditional lookbehind, but that's way beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using this regex:

```
[.]([^.&=]+)(?=[^=&]*=)
```

And replace using:

```
[$1]
```

**RegEx BreakUp:**

- `[.]` - Match a literal DOT
- `([^.&=]+)` - Match 1 or more of characters that are not one of`[.&=]`
- `(?=[^=&]*=)` - Lookahead to assert we have a `=` ahead without encountering `&`

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5IzNov/3)

Comment: Amazing, this works. That was fast. Thanks a lot for your time.